# Vimeo API channel getting number of videos

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

Wehn I query this channel ID 223872:

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/channels#get_channel

With the following fields:

```
metadata.connections.videos
```

I get response of total 56 videos:

```
{
 "metadata": {
     "connections": {
  "videos": {
    "uri": "/channels/223872/videos",
    "options": [ "GET" ],
    "total": 56
     }
   }
  }
}
```

However if I go to this channel url, I get 146 videos total:

https://vimeo.com/channels/223872

Why is there a difference?